# There are a CDN for most used Turf functions?

Tags: cdn, turfjs

The [standard CDN for `turf.min.js`](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@turf/turf@5/turf.min.js) is a ~600kb file, so big...  I am using only basic functions like `turf.bbox()` and `turf.union()`, need a ~200kb **or less** file... There are a CDN with only a basic "most frequently used" Turf functions?

---

PS: [turfjs-builder](https://turfjs-builder.herokuapp.com/) is not a CDN and stopped at 4.X Turf version... There are no use-statistics or "function curator".

Comment: Did you found it? If yes, you can share

Comment: Hi @Travnikov, it is an old post, a preliminar for [this  old discussion](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/issues/1560)

Comment: About Turf, it seems abandoned (or perhaps "perfect") because [last release is 2017](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/releases), and there are  [no commits since 2018](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/graphs/contributors)